# Using Return value from a function and performing operations on it in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: arrays, oracle, function, plsql, return

I have a function that gives ONE return value of varchar type. Till now, I used to get only one value because of certain conditions, now I am getting more than one value in the return part. So, it gives an error.
Further, I need to check that when there are more than one return value, the function should return only one of them according to certain condition.

I tried to store the return value in some array/table inside that function using some loop, but since that function will be used multiple times, it should be dynamic.
Then after getting an array with return values (say we get 3 return values), it should select one based on the value that it returns.
For eg, if the function returns "R", "Y", "B" it should first store all these values in an array and then return "R" only.

Comment: I tried using execute immediate inside the function to store it the return values in table like - execute immediate 'INSERT INTO XX_PRIORITY_TABLE VALUES('||return_value||')'; but when I try to run this it gave me an error ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at "APPS.XX_PRIORITY_TEST", line 70
ORA-06512: at "APPS.XX_PRIORITY_TEST", line 70
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

Comment: It's hard to give you a proper answer based on just this description of your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please show us the function specification and your code's calling of it.

Comment: If your function contains a query that could return more than one row, it would be more efficient to limit the results of the query using `fetch first` etc, rather than storing all of the results in shared memory before discarding all but the first one.

Answer (score 0):

With the details you have provided I would implement inside the function the control to return only one value, something like this (a simple structure, I haven't check the syntax to make it fully correct):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(RETURN VARCHAR2) AS
    v_numrows INTEGER;
    v_output VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_numrows
    FROM my_original_query;

    IF v_numrows = 1 THEN
        SELECT x INTO v_output
        FROM my_original_query;
    ELSE
        -- Alternate logic to return only one value in v_output
    END;
    RETURN v_output;
END
```

Or if you can implement the logic to select your preferred value with the logic in one query, you could use this alternate option:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(RETURN VARCHAR2) AS
    v_output VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT x INTO v_output
    FROM (  SELECT x,
                   CASE WHEN x = 'R' THEN 1
                        WHEN x = 'Y' THEN 2
                        ELSE 3
                   END order_result
            FROM my_original_query
            ORDER BY order_result
         ) order_query
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
    RETURN v_output;
END
```

The **order_query** subquery has an `ORDER BY` clause that allows you to return multiple rows in the order you prefer, and using the clause `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` ensures that you get only the first row of that subquery.